# QGIS Layer Order Panel - add layers at top of layer order

Tags: qgis

I have a QGIS workspace in which the order of the layers is controlled by the Layer Order Panel.  When I add a layer it automatically ends up at the bottom of the order and has to be manually shifted to the top so that it's visible.  Is it possible in the options to specify that added layers end up at the top of the layer order instead of the bottom?

Comment: No, not to my knowledge, looks as a WAD (WorkAsDesigned). Why do you need to control the rendering order in the Layer Order Panel, when you have the same in TOC (TableOfContent/layercontrol). In the TOC a layer will normally be added one layer above the selected layer.

Comment: I have the workspace set up with the TOC themed by different types of data which need to be displayed in a different order to make them appear correctly in the map - it's for the use of an inexperienced GIS user so set up for ease of interpretation.  It doesn't really matter, it's just an irritant when I add layers to the project!