# Error in executing Voronoi polygon algorithm

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am trying to  create Voronoi polygon on point layer of my project. I need to save this new layer as .shp file.

The following is the code I have written in Python console, using QGIS 3.0

```
import processing
Parameters={ 'INPUT' : 'file:///C:/Test/points.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=Lat&yField=Long', 'BUFFER' : 0, 'OUTPUT' : 'file:///C:/Test/vor.shp' }
processing.run('qgis:voronoipolygons',Parameters)
```

But I am getting the following error:

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 84, in run
return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 190, in runAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.
```

Answer (score 3):

I realized my mistake: the output path was not correct. The solution is:

```
import processing
parameters={ 'INPUT' : 'file:///C:/Test/points.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=Lat&yField=Long', 'BUFFER' : 0, 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Test/demand/Demand.shp' }
processing.run('qgis:voronoipolygons',parameters)
```