# Export selected fields from attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, export

In my attribute table there is a large number of fields. I want to export the data with selected fields.

How to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Are you asking how to select features and copy and paste them?

Comment: what kind of export do you expect to have ? you can also use the `Save only selected features` in `Save Vector Layer as ...`

Comment: @Taras I think they want to only save a selection of *columns* (fields) rather than features (rows).

Comment: @Spacedman, I can barely imagine this ... Besides the output format was not specified

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two ways:

1. The "Save Vector Layer" dialog lets me choose which fields to save.

[image]

2. Use either the "Drop Fields" or "Retain Fields" processing tools (in the "Vector Table" section of the processing toolbox) to create a new temporary scratch layer with a new set of fields. Then export that and delete it if you won't need it again.

You can probably set up a graphical model to do all this if you are going to be doing this a number of times.

Comment: its working!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

I could suggest a PyQGIS way of implementing this task.

```py
# referring to a needed layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# creating a temporal layer from selected features
temp_layer = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(layer.selectedFeatureIds()))

# specifying important fields
needed_fields = ["id"]
all_fields = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]
other_fields = list(set(all_fields) - set(needed_fields))

# getting indexes of other fields
idx = [temp_layer.fields().indexFromName(field) for field in other_fields]

# deleting other fields based on their indexes
temp_layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes(idx)
temp_layer.updateFields()

# adding temporal output to the map canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(temp_layer)
```

---

**References:**

- [Getting field names of a layer in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347126/getting-field-names-of-a-layer-in-pyqgis)
- [How to delete column/field in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109078/how-to-delete-column-field-in-pyqgis)
- [Adding multiple layer on Map Canvas using pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294697/adding-multiple-layer-on-map-canvas-using-pyqgis)
- [Getting attributes of selected features using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31799/getting-attributes-of-selected-features-using-pyqgis/421263#421263)

Comment: A bit complicat for such a task!?!

Comment: @katagena seems like. I agree @_@